# Есть ли возможность в sql функцией MAX() выбирать из строки число?

Tags: sqlite, база-данных, sql

Если тип данных во вхождении -- строка, то MAX() выбирает по алфавиту. То есть 12 будет меньше, чем 2. Есть ли возможность всё-таки делать выборку в строке, как по числу, независимо от типа данных? чтобы 12 было больше, чем 2, даже если 12 и 2 -- просто строки? субд -- sqlite.

Comment: вам нужно определить свою процедуру которая будет возвращать како-то значение (напр числовое) в зависимости от значения поля. как вариант она может конвертировать строку в число. итд итп.

`select max(some_func(<some_field>)) from some_table`

Comment: спасибо, думал всё сложнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX("str" + 0) AS "num_max" FROM "table"
```